# can I specify a program to always run as administrator?

Tags: windows

I sometimes forget to open VS as administrator or some other IDE such as titanium.
is there any way to specify under windows that I want a program to always run as administrator?

Comment: Super user migration candidate?

Answer (score 1):

Right click and open "Properties".

Click on "Advanced Button" at the bottom of the "Shortcut" tab

Check "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to accomplish this.

1. appcompat: create a shortcut, open its properties, click "compatibility", check "run as administrator.
2. manifests: you can add a manifest to exe files to tell windows what privilege level is required. more details on this here:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
   you want especially the "requireAdministrator" flag
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

if you need more detailed explanations just ask, i have a manifest template on another computer i can post if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running W7 then yes - right click the short cut and look at Properties > Advanced Properties.  You should see an option there to "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. These works on Windows:
Right click on the icon of the program -> Properties -> Compatibility -> "Run this program as administrator"

Next time you will use it as administrator.